# Kibana 6 - Limite size results of dashboard/search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I'm using Kibana 6 with ES 6.

I created nice KibanaDashboard with mulitple simple search. Everything is working great, BUT ... I just can't controls maxResultsSize ....

I really need to reduce this results size, dashboard is requesting & loading **100M**+ doc each time I open my dashboard.

I don't want to reboot ES&Kibana service, It have to be in dashboad json exported, to be able to re-use it.

I can't use "kibana advanced options"

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html

It have to be exclusive to my dashboard, and only mine.

I don't know why this feature is not possible in Kabana ...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you adjust the timeframe to be smaller so that you have fewer results?

Comment: You're right. I used Streaming to index and use ingest Date as "principal" Date in Kibana.
They asked me "from -15" to "from -7d" ... and obvisouly I got perf issue.

That's why I wanted to :
-"from 7d" AND "results Size limit 1 000" as example.

Comment: You're getting a performance issue because your visualizations in Kibana are mostly aggregations. Limiting the number of results isn't going to help there. You need to filter your results down in order to get better performance.